# Add custom text with sale dates after sale price in Woocommerce Single product

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, price

I have this code which adds a text after the sale price and it's generating an error in the log saying "doing it wrong" even though there is no PHP error in the functions file.

Any idea why it's "complaining" ? Here's the code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'sale_dates_after_price', 100, 2 );
function sale_dates_after_price( $price, $product ) {
    $sales_price_from = get_post_meta( $product->id, '_sale_price_dates_from', true );
    $sales_price_to   = get_post_meta( $product->id, '_sale_price_dates_to', true );
    if ( is_single() && $product->is_on_sale() && $sales_price_to != "" ) {
        $sales_price_date_from = date( "j M y", $sales_price_from );
        $sales_price_date_to   = date( "j M y", $sales_price_to );
        $price = str_replace( '</ins>', ' </ins> <span class="sale-dates"><b>offer valid between ' . $sales_price_date_from . ' and ' . $sales_price_date_to . '</b></span>', $price );
    }
    return apply_filters( 'woocommerce_get_price', $price );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is outdated with some errors and mistakes… As you are using **the formatted sale price**, there is a much better hook for that. Try the following:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_format_sale_price', 'sale_dates_after_price', 10, 3 );
function sale_dates_after_price ( $price, $regular_price, $sale_price ) {
    global $product;

    if( ! is_a($product, 'WC_Product') ) 
        return $price;

    $date_from = $product->get_date_on_sale_from();
    $date_to   = $product->get_date_on_sale_to();

    if( is_product() && ! ( empty($date_from) && empty($date_to) ) ) {
        $date_from = date( "j M y", strtotime($date_from) );
        $date_to   = date( "j M y", strtotime($date_to) );
        $price    .= ' <span class="sale-dates"><strong>offer valid between '.$date_from.' and '.$date_to.'</strong></span>';
    }

    return $price;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

[image]

Comment: after updating and going to cart it's complaining about this line: `$date_from = $product->get_date_on_sale_from();` and saying that it's a `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_date_on_sale_from() on null`. Any ideas why?

Comment: Thanks @LoicTheAztec but I found a little error in if condition: you check double time $date_from instead of $date_to